# Reading and writing xml file to database in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

i have problem with service xml file. I dont get any errors but my xml file dont writing to mysql.

Program only create some batch and task tables in mysql, but doesn't write value into them.
I'm new in springboot and don't have any idea whats wrong with this code.

Here is my BatchConfiguration class.

```
package com.projekt.springboot;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.ItemPreparedStatementSetter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {
 
 @Autowired
 public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
 
 @Autowired
 public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
 
 @Autowired
 private DataSource dataSource;
 
 @Bean
 public StaxEventItemReader<Task> reader(){
  StaxEventItemReader<Task> reader = new StaxEventItemReader<Task>();
  reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("new1.xml"));
  reader.setFragmentRootElementName("task");
  
  Map<String, String> aliases = new HashMap<String, String>();
  aliases.put("user", "com.projekt.springboot.Task");
  
  XStreamMarshaller xStreamMarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
  xStreamMarshaller.setAliases(aliases);
  
  reader.setUnmarshaller(xStreamMarshaller);
  System.out.println(reader);
  return reader;
 }
 
 @Bean
 public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Task> writer(){
  JdbcBatchItemWriter<Task> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<Task>();
  writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
  writer.setSql("INSERT INTO task(id,name,surname,login) VALUES (:id,:name,:surname,:login)");
  writer.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(new UserItemPreparedStmSetter());
  
  return writer;
 }
 
 private class UserItemPreparedStmSetter implements ItemPreparedStatementSetter<Task>{

  @Override
  public void setValues(Task task, PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
   ps.setLong(1, task.getId());
   ps.setString(2, task.getName());
   ps.setString(3, task.getSurname());
   ps.setString(4, task.getLogin());
  }
  
 }
 
 @Bean
 public Step step1() {
  return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
    .<Task, Task> chunk(10)
    .reader(reader())
    .writer(writer())
    .build();
 }
 
 @Bean
 public Job importUserJob() {
  return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
    .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
    .flow(step1())
    .end()
    .build();
    
 }
}
```

Task.class

```
package com.projekt.springboot;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "task")
public class Task {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String surname;

    @Column
    private String login;
    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }
}
```

new1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users>
    <user>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>name1</name>
        <surname>surname1</surname>
        <login>login1</login>
    </user>
    <user>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>name2</name>
        <surname>surname2</surname>
        <login>login2</login>
    </user>
</users>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
spring.batch.initialize-schema=ALWAYS
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```